# check shell scripts

Tags: shell, scripting

is there any software, like lint for C, to check shell scripts ?

check

1. the syntax
2. the compatibility with bash ksh etc...

online web service or installable as program

I don't want to run and debug. I am looking for static analisys, as lint for C.

Comment: I know of [`checkbasisms`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/checkbaskisms/).

Comment: @Jeff Schaller nope see my edit

Comment: checkbasisms : I click on 'checkbashisms Web Site' ... it open a web page 'forbidden' ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like using ShellCheck. You can find it online at [www.shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) or download for your disto from GitHub or the ShellCheck site.